# Plugin won't activate - cannot declare class (already in use)

Tags: plugins, activation

I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm using the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](http://wppb.io/)

When activating my blank plugin, I receive the following error.

`Fatal error: Cannot declare class Requests, because the name is already in use in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/requests/includes/class-Requests.php on line 30`

here's the code of that page up to line 30:

```
<?php

/**
 * The file that defines the core plugin class
 *
 * A class definition that includes attributes and functions used across both the
 * public-facing side of the site and the admin area.
 *
 * @link       http://codykaczynski.com
 * @since      1.0.0
 *
 * @package    Requests
 * @subpackage Requests/includes
 */

/**
 * The core plugin class.
 *
 * This is used to define internationalization, admin-specific hooks, and
 * public-facing site hooks.
 *
 * Also maintains the unique identifier of this plugin as well as the current
 * version of the plugin.
 *
 * @since      1.0.0
 * @package    Requests
 * @subpackage Requests/includes
 * @author     Cody Kaczynski <ckazynski@ampedsound.net>
 */
class Requests {
```

all i've done so far is replace PLUGIN_NAME and its variations with Requests, as it says in the installation directions on GitHub.

I'm sorry for such a dumb question, just not sure what's going on? I don't know anything about the WordPress API or OOP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because WordPress already have class named Request

[`https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/)

When creating a plugin or using boilerplate to generate, you should add prefix for your plugin name/class name, or avoid using very basic name.

Example:

```
class Wpse309780_Request
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        # code...
    }
}
```